# ! Font \TU/lmr/m/n/10=[lmroman10-regular]:+tlig; at 10pt not loadable

Tags: errors, luatex, texlive, windows

I'm on Windows (seems like everyone else is using *nix + latex, so I thought it's worth pointing out).

When I run this command in the command prompt:

```
lualatex.exe --halt-on-error --interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=C:\ C:\Users\uuu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp9DE6.tex
```

The error I get is:

```
! Font \TU/lmr/m/n/10=[lmroman10-regular]:+tlig; at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.
<to be read again>
relax
l.105 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont

 372 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 rule, 1 dir, 4 glue, 47 glue_spec, 2 if_stack, 2 write, 1 pdf_col
orstack nodes
   avail lists: 2:13,3:3,5:2,7:2,8:1,9:2
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on tmp9DE6.log.
```

When I try to generate pdf file using TeXworks tool however, it's being generated properly. The question is - which command line options is it using to not have the same problem as cmd has? Or more general - what to do to make this problem go away?

EDIT:

Huh, didn't notice this earlier because of the amount of output, but one of the first things console is showing after running the above command, is:

`module 'luaotfload-main' not found`

Maybe that's the real problem? But what is the reason for it?

Comment: Which distribution are you using? MikTeX? TeX Live?

Comment: It's TeX Live. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Compare the log-files. Perhaps you have two texsystems.

Comment: What should I look for?

Comment: you should have that file in `texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-main.lua` try updating your system to install luaotfload

Comment: Simply *look*. You are in the happy situation that you have a failing and a working compilation. So you can compare both and search for differences.

Comment: The problem is that this lua script is where it's supposed to be :(

Comment: save the log file you get when you call via texworks and the log file you get if you call directly and compare line by line and see where they start using different files (or different version of latex)

Comment: Btw: You shouldn't use C: as output directory.

Comment: Where were I right?

Comment: `Perhaps you have two texsystems` - my texlive install dir contains the 2016 folder inside. I was using `lualatex` from `C:\texlive\bin\win32` but I should be using the one installed in `C:\texlive\2016\bin\win32`

Comment: Radon Rosborough's `sudo apt-get install fonts-lmodern` in question 129799 was the solution (for me).

Answer (score 12):

In case someone else comes across this problem, the solution is to install luaotfload:

```
sudo tlmgr install luaotfload
```

Comment: I needed `luaotfload-tool --update` in addition to that.

Comment: If using Tex Live in Debian, this installs `loaotfload-main`, and fixes the problem: `sudo apt-get install texlive-luatex`. And this is needed for the `lualatex` command: `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base`.

Comment: @pts It works perfectly!

Comment: FINALLY! I spent days trying to figure out the font crap. Everything about package fontspec said "need lualatex" which I had. Installing `texlive-luatex` finally made my fonts work. This is on Debian testing, Oct 2022.

Answer (score 8):

I solved this problem by explicitly installing the `texlive-luatex` package.

On Arch Linux, the command for this installation would be

```
sudo pacman -S texlive-luatex
```

Comment: In my case, [it was not the solution](https://i.imgur.com/xduaz2d.png).

Comment: The solution [was](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/691766/117967).

Comment: I had that problem on Debian.  Package name is the same:  `sudo apt install texlive-luatex`

Comment: (Thanks !) Indeed, in archlinux the texlive package seems to have been recently splitted, and you may have other error because of missing packages.