# ! Font \TU/lmr/m/n/12=[lmroman12-regular]:+tlig; at 12pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad

Tags: luatex, miktex, miktex2.9

I'm currently using MikTeX 2.9.6809 and LuaTeX 1.07.0, and I cannot compile in LuaLaTeX (I can compile in XeLaTeX and pdfTex though).

I fully updated MikTeX after encountering this error, still not fixing this issue. Even the most basic Hello World doesn't want to compile.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

What am I missing that could cause this error ?

Using 12pt :

```
(D:/Users/xxx.xxx/Documents/Software/MikTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base
/size12.clo
! Font \TU/lmr/m/n/12=[lmroman12-regular]:+tlig; at 12pt not loadable: metric d
ata not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
relax 
l.54 \normalsize
```

Using 11 pt:

```
(D:/Users/xxx.xxx/Documents/Software/MikTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base
/size11.clo
! Font \TU/lmr/m/n/10.95=[lmroman10-regular]:+tlig; at 10.95pt not loadable: me
tric data not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
relax 
l.54 \normalsize
```

Using 10pt (Not specifying a font size in the documentclass)

```
(D:/Users/xxx.xxx/Documents/Software/MikTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base
/size10.clo
! Font \TU/lmr/m/n/10=[lmroman10-regular]:+tlig; at 10pt not loadable: metric d
ata not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
relax 
l.54 \normalsize
```

Thanks in advance

Edit : The only related problem I found [! Font \TU/lmr/m/n/10=[lmroman10-regular]:+tlig; at 10pt not loadable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378488/font-tu-lmr-m-n-10-lmroman10-regulartlig-at-10pt-not-loadable) won't help, as it was using TeX Live

Comment: your link to a "linux-specific" answer is in fact to a question about windows (but it doesn't help you anyway as it is texlive rather than miktex)

Comment: Oh, nevermind then, I mostly saw the answer using `sudo` so I assumed it was *nix

Comment: I encoutered the very same problem yesterday.. So maybe there is something wrong with miktex.. Haven't found a solution so far.. Currently I am working with an older offline setup

Comment: I also use other compilers for now, but some packages I need use LuaLaTeX unfortunately

Comment: Did it worked before? For me the error came suddenly, the days before it worked without any problems

Comment: is this luatex 1.08? (and did you get an error before this from luaotfload?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (MiKTeX 2.9.6800) `, and no error from luaotfload

Comment: @sporc It used to work last time I used it, a few weeks back

Comment: The problem for me was again from package `stmaryrd`. This package after updating may need one PdfTex compilation for fixing: even if the error message only mentions Times, the issue has nothing to do with Times, which can be extremely tricky to solve when you are not informed of that.

Answer (score 3):

For me the fix was to run:

`luaotfload-tool --update --force`

As suggested here: https://github.com/gregorio-project/gregorio/issues/1458#issuecomment-499215969

Comment: Thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 1):

With an current version of MiKTeX I can compile without errors or warnings, see the `.log` file:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.09.0 (MiKTeX 2.9.6880 64-bit)  (format=lualatex 2018.11.18)  19 DEC 2018 13:48
 restricted system commands enabled.
**449614.tex
(./449614.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2018-10-28 2.93 luaotfload entry point
Lua module: luaotfload-init 2018-10-28 2.93 luaotfload submodule / initializatio
n
Lua module: lualibs 2018-10-18 2.61 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2018-10-18 2.61 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
Lua module: luaotfload-log 2018-10-28 2.93 luaotfload submodule / logging
Lua module: luaotfload-parsers 2018-10-28 2.93 luaotfload submodule / filelist
Lua module: luaotfload-configuration 2018-10-28 2.93 luaotfload submodule / conf
ig file reader
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is C:/Users/Internet/AppData/Local/MiKT
eX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/names.
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader “fontloader-2018-10-28.lua” from kpse
-resolved path “C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2
018-10-28.lua”.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@state = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 2
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 3
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version “3.106”
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Lua module: luaotfload-loaders 2018-10-28 2.93 luaotfload submodule / callback h
andling
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-database 2018-10-28 2.93 luaotfload submodule / database
Lua module: luaotfload-colors 2018-10-28 2.93 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 4
Lua module: luaotfload-resolvers 2018-10-28 2.93 luaotfload submodule / resolver
s
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is C:/Users/Internet/AppData/Local/MiKT
eX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/names.
Lua module: luaotfload-features 2018-10-28 2.93 luaotfload submodule / features
Lua module: luaotfload-letterspace 2018-10-28 2.93 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-auxiliary 2018-10-28 2.93 luaotfload submodule / auxiliar
y functions
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.688 seconds
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/report.cls"
Document Class: report 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/size12.clo"
File: size12.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from C:/Users/Internet/AppData/Loca
l/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc)
\c@part=\count80
\c@chapter=\count81
\c@section=\count82
\c@subsection=\count83
\c@subsubsection=\count84
\c@paragraph=\count85
\c@subparagraph=\count86
\c@figure=\count87
\c@table=\count88
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (./449614.aux)
\openout1 = 449614.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.

[1

{C:/Users/Internet/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(./449614.aux))

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 239 strings out of 494324
 100000,89155 words of node,token memory allocated
 382 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 45 glue_spec,
 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:15,3:2,4:1,5:22,6:1,7:24,9:7
 4535 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+200000
 15 fonts using 723495 bytes
 22i,4n,20p,132b,121s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<c:/program files/miktex 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman12-regular.otf>
Output written on 449614.pdf (1 page, 3825 bytes).

PDF statistics: 13 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

Some time ago there was a problem with MiKTeX, LuaLaTeX and `luaotfload`. `luaotfload` was buggy.  The current version does not have this bug ...