# Arch Linux: Fontspec does not find *.ttf-Font (LuaLaTex)

Tags: luatex, fontspec, texlive

Since the last update to the newest TexLive version, a corporate designed `scrlttr2`-document does not compile anymore.

I always receive errors about a missing font:

> Font \TU/lmr/m/n/10=[lmroman10-regular]:+tlig; at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad. ...lt\familydefault\seriesdefault\shapedefault

> Package fontspec Error: The font "LinotypeSyntaxCom-Regular" cannot be(fontspec) found.

> Font \TU/LinotypeSyntaxCom(0)/m/n/10=[/usr/local/share/fonts/linotype-syntax-cdable: metric data not found or bad.

There are definitely all mentioned `Linotype.ttf-fonts` stored in `/usr/local/share/fonts/linotype-syntax-com/` directory.

---

Therefore I have tried to recall the fonts in the document by:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
Path           = /usr/local/share/fonts/linotype-syntax-com/,
Extension      = .ttf ,
UprightFont    = *-Regular,
BoldFont       = *-Bold,
ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
BoldItalicFont = *-BoldIt,
]{LinotypeSyntaxCom}


\begin{document}
    Something is wrong! I am momentarily blinded and confused by moving, overlapping, translucent images that overwhelm my vision of the book I am reading.
\end{document}
```

But this didn't work.

---

**Any ideas how to solve this?**

In LibreOffice all fonts are still available.

Comment: Your first message seems to say that even lmroman10-regular is not found  and that would mean that something is really  broken. What happens with a hello world example without fontspec and \setmainfont?

Comment: Did you install TexLive through `pacman`/`pamac` or with the perl script from the [TUG Website](https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html)?

Comment: If you used `pacman`, (1) are you using Arch or a derivative? and (2) did you use `pacman` or a wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

Install [texlive-fontsrecommended](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/texlive-fontsrecommended/files), it has `/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf`.
It will vanish the first error.

I do not have own copy for these Linotype Syntax font. Please confirm @Dave.

> PS: [Looks like a bad practice install over `/usr/local`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Creating_packages#build()) (off-topic comment).

Comment: Why are you certain the OP didn't install vanilla TeX Live? Why do you think the location of the fonts shows any kind of installation problem? Arch packages shouldn't install into `/usr/local`, but there's no reason Arch users shouldn't install stuff there which is not managed by `pacman`. That is part of the point: to keep the stuff `pacman` manages separate from stuff installed in other ways. Note that your advice could easily make things worse rather than better if the OP is using vanilla TL. In that case, doing as you suggest will muddle things further.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.